# Determine whether a point is inside a partial cone

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone please help me with a way to determine whether a point, given as (px,py,pz) is inside a "partial upside down" cone. The cone is always aligned with the z-axis. The cone is defined with height, bottom radius, top radius, x and y where:

-height is the z value of the top of the cone. The bottom of the cone is always on the xy plane.
-bottom radius is the radius of the cone at the bottom.
-top radius is the radius of the cone at the top. (top radius >= bottom radius)
-x and y is the position of the centre point if the cone on the xy plane

NOTE: The given point's Z coordinate will always be between the bottom and top of the cone.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you.find an equation for the disk you get when you slice the cone at some arbitrary value $z$? Then, given your point, you only need to determine whether $(p_x,p_y)$ is contained in this 2-dimensional disk at height $z = p_z$.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to. That is what my problem boils down to... I need to calculate the radius of the cone at a certain z value.

Comment: It's simpler than you might have thought: the radius is a linear function of $z$. So if at height $0$ the radius is $r_0$, and at height $h$ the radius is $r_h$, then at height $0 < z < h$ the radius is $r_0 + z \cdot (r_h - r_0)/h$. (You can verify that this is correct by substituting $z = 0$ to get $r_0$ and $z = h$ to get $r_h$.)

Comment: Thank you so much TMM. That works perfectly. If you paste it as a solution I will give you my thumbs up.

Answer (score 0):

Let the cone be defined by the height $h$, bottom radius $r_0$ (at $z = 0$), and top radius $r_h$ (at $z = h$), and the $x$ and $y$ coordinates $c_x, c_y$ of the center of the cone, and let the point be described by $p = (p_x, p_y, p_z)$.

As the radius of the cone at height $z \in [0, h]$ scales linearly with $z$, we can find a formula for $r_z$, the radius at arbitrary height $z$:

$$r_z = r_0 + \frac{z}{h} (r_h - r_0) = \frac{(h-z) \cdot r_0 + z \cdot r_h}{h}. \qquad (z \in [0, h])$$

Observe that indeed $r_z \to r_0$ as $z \to 0$ and $r_z \to r_h$ as $z \to h$.

Finally, given a point $p = (p_x, p_y, p_z)$, to figure out if it is inside this cone, we must check whether $(p_x, p_y)$ is inside the circle at center $(c_x, c_y)$ and radius $r_z$ with $z = p_z$. This corresponds to checking whether the following condition holds:

$$(p_x - c_x)^2 + (p_y - c_y)^2 \quad \stackrel{?}{\leq} \quad r_{p_z}^2.$$

If you want to have an explicit condition in terms of the original variables, we can simply substitute the earlier formula for $r_z$ to obtain

$$h^2 (p_x - c_x)^2 + h^2 (p_y - c_y)^2 \quad \stackrel{?}{\leq} \quad \left[(h-p_z) \cdot r_0 + p_z \cdot r_h\right]^2.$$

If this evaluates to true, it is inside the cone, while if this condition is not satisfied the point $p$ lies outside the cone.